# How to apply Client Side validation using Fluent Validation for .Net core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, fluentvalidation, .net-core-3.0, fluentvalidation-2.0

.Net Core 3.0 MVC view. Needs to apply - Client Side validation for below model.

Tried as follow:

Model:Person

```
public class Person {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public int Age { get; set; }
    }
```

Validation Rules:

```
public class PersonValidator : AbstractValidator<Person> {
    public PersonValidator() {
        RuleFor(x => x.Id).NotNull().NotEmpty();
        RuleFor(x => x.Name).Length(0, 10);
        RuleFor(x => x.Email).EmailAddress();
        RuleFor(x => x.Age).InclusiveBetween(18, 60);
    }
}
```

Followed documentation, it shows, "validator" attribute but I could not find in namespace.

https://docs.fluentvalidation.net/en/latest/mvc5.html

Comment: this [link](https://ml-software.ch/posts/extending-client-side-validation-with-fluentvalidation-and-jquery-unobtrusive-in-an-asp-net-core-application) maybe helpful for you

Answer (score 1):

## Solution 1: Use `AddFluentValidationClientsideAdapters`

Beware, because the library is no longer supported:

> We no longer recommend using this approach for new projects but it is still available for legacy implementations.

You may use the `FluentValidation.AspNetCore` and register the client-side validation by adding:

```cs
services.AddFluentValidationClientsideAdapters();
```

## Solution 2: Use FormHelper

You may also use the [FormHelper](https://github.com/sinanbozkus/FormHelper) and, *instead of using client-side validation you could instead execute your full server-side rules via AJAX*.

## Details

The [FluentValidation GitHub readme](https://github.com/FluentValidation/FluentValidation.AspNetCore#clientside-validation) says:

> ## Clientside Validation
>
> FluentValidation is a server-library and does not provide any
> client-side validation directly. However, it can provide metadata
> which can be applied to the generated HTML elements for use with a
> client-side framework such as jQuery Validate in the same way that
> ASP.NET's default validation attributes work.
>
> Note that not all rules defined in FluentValidation will work with
> ASP.NET's client-side validation. For example, any rules defined using
> a condition (with When/Unless), custom validators, or calls to Must
> will not run on the client side. Nor will any rules in a `RuleSet`
> (although this can be changed - see below). The following validators
> are supported on the client:
>
> - `NotNull`/`NotEmpty`
> - `Matches` (regex)
> - `InclusiveBetween` (range)
> - `CreditCard`
> - `Email`
> - `EqualTo` (cross-property equality comparison)
> - `MaxLength`
> - `MinLength`
> - `Length`
>
> To enable clientside integration you need to install the
> FluentValidation.AspNetCore package and call the
> AddFluentValidationClientsideAdapters in your application startup:
>
> ```
> public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
> {
>     services.AddMvc();
>     services.AddFluentValidationClientsideAdapters();
>     services.AddScoped<IValidator<Person>, PersonValidator>();
>     // etc
> }
> ```
>
> Note that the `AddFluentValidationClientsideAdapters` method is only available in FluentValidation 11.1 and newer. In older versions,
> you should use the `AddFluentValidation` method which enables both
> auto-validation and clientside adapters. If you only want clientside
> adapters and don't want auto validation in 11.0 and older, you can
> configure this by calling `services.AddFluentValidation(config => config.AutomaticValidationEnabled = false)`
>
> Alternatively, instead of using client-side validation you could
> instead execute your full server-side rules via AJAX using a library
> such as [FormHelper](https://github.com/sinanbozkus/FormHelper). This allows you to use the full power of
> FluentValidation, while still having a responsive user experience.
>
> ### Specifying a RuleSet for client-side messages
>
> If you're using rulesets alongside ASP.NET MVC, then you'll notice
> that by default FluentValidation will only generate client-side error
> messages for rules not part of any ruleset. You can instead specify
> that FluentValidation should generate clientside rules from a
> particular ruleset by attributing your controller action with a
> `RuleSetForClientSideMessagesAttribute`:
>
> ```
> [RuleSetForClientSideMessages("MyRuleset")]
> public ActionResult Index(){ return View(new Person()); }
> ```
>
> You can also use the SetRulesetForClientsideMessages extension method
> within your controller action, which has the same affect:
>
> ```
> public ActionResult Index()
> {   
>    ControllerContext.SetRulesetForClientsideMessages("MyRuleset");   
>    return View(new Person());
> }
> ```
>
> You can force all rules to be used to generate client-side error
> message by specifying a ruleset of "*".

## Read more

Read more at:

- [GitHub](https://github.com/FluentValidation/FluentValidation.AspNetCore#clientside-validation)
- [Documentation](https://docs.fluentvalidation.net/en/latest/aspnet.html)

Comment: Note: FluentValidation.AspNetCore is deprecated and no longer supported. FormHelper seems to be the currently recommended alternative. See https://docs.fluentvalidation.net/en/latest/aspnet.html

Answer (score 0):

Was able to figure it out.

this needs to be added under, Startup file, `.AddMvc().AddFluentValidation()`

So, it automatically able to pick the validation at client side as well as server side.
Thanks.